# Concatenate two data frames to a data frame of square matrix

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes of which shapes are "n x n" and "m x n" (m < n). For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,0]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,1]])
```

I'd like to get the dataframe of a square matrix by concatenating above dataframes:

```
df3 = foo(df1, df2)
print df3.values
```

This should print like the following matrix.

```
[[0,1,0,1,1,1],
 [1,0,0,1,1,1],
 [0,0,0,1,1,0],
 [1,1,1,0,0,1],
 [1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [1,1,0,1,0,0]]
```

The logic of concatination is like this:

1. the upper-left part of the square matrix comes from df1
2. the upper-right part of it comes from the transpose of df2
3. the bottom-left part of it comes from df2
4. all element of the rest of it (bottom-right part) is zero.

How do I implement the above logic (`foo` method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample of `foo`:

```
def foo(_df1,_df2):
    df1 = _df1.reset_index(drop=True) #to make sure the index is ordered
    df2 = _df2.reset_index(drop=True) #to make sure the index is ordered
    df2_transpose = df2.transpose().reset_index(drop=True) #reset the index to match the join below

    df_upper = df1.join(df2_transpose,rsuffix="_") #add suffix for additional columns
    df_upper.columns = [i for i in range(df_upper.shape[1])] #reset column names to int

    df = pd.concat([df_upper,df2]) #fill the bottom left

    df.fillna(0,inplace=True) #fill with 0 the bottom right

    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

The foo function:

```
def foo(df1_data,df2_data):

    df_test = pd.concat([df1_data,df2_data])
    a = np.concatenate((df2_data.values.T,np.zeros(shape = (df_test.values.shape[0] - df_test.values.shape[1],df2_data.values.shape[0]))))
    final_array = np.append(df_test.values,a, axis=1).astype(int)
    df3_data = pd.DataFrame(final_array)

    return df3_data

df3 = foo(df1,df2)
```